# How to plot in log-linear BASE 2 using BASIC plot() - no ggplot?

Tags: r, plot

In full disclosure I have asked a similar - but different - question about plotting in log-linear without restricting to the basic R plot function and using time series.

I have been able to get ALMOST what I am after, but in log base 10. I need base 2. Here is the code as is:

```
require(RCurl)
require(foreign)
require(tidyverse)
x = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv")
corona = read.csv(text = x, sep =",",header = T)
corona <- corona %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(`Province.State`, `Country.Region`, Lat, Long),
               names_to = "date",
               values_to = "cases")
corona <- corona[,c("Country.Region","date","cases")]
corona <- corona[!is.na(corona$cases), ]

Spain <- corona[corona$Country.Region=='Spain',]
Spain <- Spain[Spain$cases>1,]
startDate <- as.Date("2020-02-09")
xm <- seq(startDate, by="1 day", length.out=nrow(Spain))
#plot(Spain$cases~xm, type='l', ylab="No. Cov-19 cases", xlab='', lwd=3, col=2,
#     main = "No. Cov-19 in Spain")


Italy <- corona[corona$Country.Region=='Italy',]
Italy <- Italy[(nrow(Italy)-nrow(Spain)+1):nrow(Italy),]
plot(Italy$cases~xm, type='l', ylab="No. Cov-19 cases", xlab='', lwd=3,
    log="y", col=2, las=2, 
    main = "No. Cov-19 in Italy (red) v Spain (blue)")

lines(Spain$cases~xm, type='l', ylab="No. Cov-19 cases", xlab='', lwd=3, col=4)
```

---

Here is the plot I want to get but with the most recent data, which puts the maximum number of cases at the time of the writing at 17,660, and dates in the x axis:

[image]

---

Combo of both answers:

```
require(RCurl)
require(foreign)
require(tidyverse) # To tip the df from long row of dates to cols (pivot_longer())
x = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv")

corona = (read_csv(x)
          %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(`Province/State`, `Country/Region`, Lat, Long),
                           names_to = "date",
                           values_to = "cases")
          %>% select(`Country/Region`, date, cases)
          %>% mutate(date=as.Date(date,format="%m/%d/%y"))
          %>% drop_na(cases)
          %>% rename(country="Country/Region")
)

cc <- (corona
       %>% filter(country %in% c("Italy","Spain", "Korea, South"))
)

ccw <- (cc
        %>% pivot_wider(names_from="country",values_from="cases")
        %>% filter(cumsum(Italy>0 | Spain>0)>=5)
)


plot(ccw$date, ccw$Italy, type="l", lwd=3,
        ylab='', 
        xlab='',
        log='y',
        col=5,
        axes=FALSE,
        main = "Log-lin cumulative COVID-19 cases in Italy and Spain v South Korea",
        cex.main=0.9)

at1 <- seq(min(ccw$date), max(ccw$date)+1, by=3);
axis.Date(1, at=at1, format="%b %d", las=2, cex.axis=0.7)


at2 <- 2^seq(1,30,by=1)
axis(side=2, at2, cex.axis=0.7)

abline(h=at2, lty=2, col="grey90")  # Add faint grid lines

lines(ccw$date, ccw$`Korea, South`, lwd=3, col=4, lty=3)
lines(ccw$date, ccw$Spain, lwd=3, col=2)

legend(ccw$date[1], 15000, legend=c("Korea", "Italy", "Spain"),
       col=c(4, 5, 2), lty=c(3,1,1), lwd=3, cex=0.8,
       box.lty=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I think the difference between natural log, log-10, and log-2 is only in scaling; the differences in ggplot (or whatever) have only to do with how you label the breaks ...

Comment: Plot log2 cases, but turn the y-axis off `yaxt="n"` and then add your own axis afterwards `axis(side=2, at=..., labels=...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Italy$cases2 <- log2(Italy$cases)
Spain$cases2 <- log2(Spain$cases)

plot(Italy$cases2~xm, type='n', ylab="No. Cov-19 cases", xlab='',
     las=2, 
     xlim=c(min(xm), max(xm)+1), # Increase x-axis by one day
     ylim=c(1, log2(max(Italy$cases))), 
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n",  # Turn off x and y-axis
     main = "No. Cov-19 in Italy (red) v Spain (blue)",
     bty='L')  

at1 <- seq(min(xm), max(xm)+1, by=3);
axis.Date(1, at=at1, format="%b %d", las=2)

at2 <- seq(from=1, to=15, by=1); # Modify these to suit
axis(side=2, at=at2, labels=2^at2, las=1)

abline(h=at, lty=2, col="grey90")  # Add faint grid lines

lines(Italy$cases2~xm, lwd=3, col=2)
lines(Spain$cases2~xm, lwd=3, col=4)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Any way to show in the x axis the last day (March 14)?

Comment: How do you calculate `at <- seq(1, 14, 3)` systematically to match the actual data?

Comment: `extra <- as.Date("2020-03-14"); 
axis(side=1, at=extra, label=format(extra, "%b %d"), las=2)`

Comment: The `axis` function aligns with the the plot axis already there, which is hidden.

Comment: Italy currently has 21,000 cases, and in the dataset I believe the maximum value is 17660. Compare to the y axis of your plot.

Comment: The plot is correct. Modify the `by` parameter in the command and you'll see.

Comment: `at <- seq(1, 16, 1); 
abline(h=at, lty=2, col="grey90"); 
axis(side=2, at=at, labels=2^at, las=1, cex.axis=0.8)`

Comment: They are evenly spread, except for Mar 14, which doesn't exist in the data. R only plots the data. Do you want to include Mar 14 (NA cases) and then evenly space the dates?

Comment: Can it be that the last point in the x-axis is March 13, for which there is data, and then everything else evenly spaced?

Comment: There are 34 days from Feb 09 to Mar 13. The best you can do is every 2 days. OK?

Comment: Will you modify the post? Also, tangentially, and before I check the green, do you think I'm uploading the data correctly?

Comment: I'm getting an error with the last edit...`> axis(side=2, at=at2, labels=2^at, las=1)
Error in axis(side = 2, at = at2, labels = 2^at, las = 1) : 
  'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 15 != 5`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209650/discussion-between-edward-and-math-stunned).

Answer (score 3):

The difference between natural log, log-10, and log-2 is only in scaling; the differences have only to do with how you label the breaks ...

Data manipulation (slightly condensed/improved?)

```
corona = (read_csv(x)
 %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(`Province/State`, `Country/Region`, Lat, Long),
                  names_to = "date",
                  values_to = "cases")
    %>% select(`Country/Region`, date, cases)
    %>% mutate(date=as.Date(date,format="%m/%d/%y"))
    %>% drop_na(cases)
    %>% rename(country="Country/Region")
)
cc <- (corona
    %>% filter(country %in% c("Italy","Spain"))
)
ccw <- (cc
    %>% pivot_wider(names_from="country",values_from="cases")
  ## select only since beginning of Italy/Spain epidemics
    %>% filter(cumsum(Italy>0 | Spain>0)>=1)
)
```

Now plot, using `matplot()`:

```
par(las=1)
matplot(ccw$date, ccw[,-1], type="l",ylab="No. Cov-19 cases", xlab='', lwd=3,
        log="y", las=2,
        col=c("red","blue"),
        axes=FALSE,
        main = "No. Cov-19 in Italy (red) v Spain (blue)")
## custom axes
axis.Date(side=1,x=ccw$date)
axis(side=2,at=2^seq(1,14,by=2))
box()
```

You can decide whether that spacing of breaks is what you want.

[image]

Comment: Any way to show in the x axis more days, including March 14?

Comment: I have also noted an "x" in front of the dates when imported as in the OP, which is not there if I use `source_data`, making the conversion to time of the `date` column much easier. I wonder if that could simplify the code.

Comment: Italy currently has 21,000 cases, and in the dataset I believe the maximum value is 17660. Compare to the y axis of your plo

Comment: Thank you! The way you manipulate the data is certainly great, and more elegant. I wish I could accept both answers.